How would I add some static text as information top of the JSON formatted list view in SharePoint online
I have a SharePoint online list view. I have formatted the view using JSON as given below. Now my requirement is to add a static text as highlighted to give some information to the visiting user. How can I add that text. Please guide.
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "height": 103,
  "width": 300,
  "hideSelection": true,
  "fillHorizontally": true,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "sp-card-container"
    },
    
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "sp-card-defaultClickButton"
        },
        "customRowAction": {
          "action": "defaultClick"
        }
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-white sp-css-borderColor-neutralLight sp-card-borderHighlight sp-card-subContainer"
        },
        "style": {
          "background-color": "whitesmoke"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "[$Title]",
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content sp-card-highlightedContent",
                  "role": "heading",
                  "aria-level": "3"
                },
                "txtContent": "=if ([$Title] == '', '–', [$Title])"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-lastTextColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "[$DetailedDescription]",
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content  sp-card-multiline"
                },
                "txtContent": "=if ([$DetailedDescription] == '', '–', [$DetailedDescription])",
                "style": {
                  "-webkit-line-clamp": "2",
                  "height": "40px",
                  "word-break": "auto-phrase"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

Thanks in advance!

You could add following code before Title elmtype.
  {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "p",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content sp-card-highlightedContent",
          "role": "heading",
          "aria-level": "3"
        },
        "txtContent": "static text as highlighted"
      }
    ]
   },



Hello Emily,
I wanted to basically add some static text on top of all the tile. meaning a information text will get displayed like the list tittle gets displayed before all the items in list gets displayed as per the schema. Hope you understood. So, can we add something like that.
